# IE10 inset box-shadow scaling with border-radius

Tags: forms, internet-explorer-10, css

I want to add an inset box-shadow in IE10. It appears that the rounded corner is scaling larger in size relatively to the border radius applied to the input element. This doesn't happen in webkit or firefox. I can see how it would make sense to scale an outset box-shadow, but it's weird to scale an inset one.

How it should look:

[image: How it should look]

How it looks in IE10:

[image: How it looks in IE10]

Has anyone ran into this before and found a solution?

Comment: My solution was to use a 5px border with a 1px outset box-shadow, instead of using a 1px border with a 5px inset box-shadow.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer
http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/

Some test code:

```
.navigation ul li a {
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #ffccff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #ffccff;
  -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #ffccff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #ffccff;
}
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
    /* IE9 and IE10 rule sets go here */
.navigation ul li a {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 17px #3a312a;
 }
}
```

Comment: I think in this case I'll let it go looking not-quite-right. But it's useful to know there are ways around the conditional comments thing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add inset box-shadow for each side of block separately and it worked!
http://codepen.io/bivihoba/pen/DHuqk